# Meteor geolocation package for android errors

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I am trying to fetch my location current location on android platform of Meteor. I followed these instructions [mdg:geolocation](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:geolocation/README.md) on web its is working perfectly, but on mobile platform (Android) when I try to run this command

```
meteor run android-device
```

it is giving me this error log.

```
Error while running for mobile platforms: Error running                            
/Users/muhammadfazilqureshi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.3rwpx3++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh
Error: version not found: 0.3.0 : org.apache.cordova.geolocation/0.3.0
at RegClient.<anonymous>
(/Users/muhammadfazilqureshi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.3rwpx3++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:272:14)
at Request.self.callback
(/Users/muhammadfazilqureshi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.3rwpx3++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Request.<anonymous>
(/Users/muhammadfazilqureshi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.3rwpx3++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>
(/Users/muhammadfazilqureshi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.3rwpx3++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:943:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I am using OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a Cordova plugins outage. See this issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3726

If you manually add the newest version with `meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.geolocation@0.3.10`, that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have the outdate version of the package(3.0.0)

Try to run the update command or `remove/add` it

```
meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.geolocation@0.3.10
```

Be sure to put the code inside a `Meteor.startup(function(){});`

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
   //Code here
});
```

Did you already take a look into this documentation? [Meteor Cordova Phonegap integration](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration)